# What is difference between typing text and click on return button in UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uitextview, uistackview

When I type the text in `UITextView` superview doesn't expand.

When I click on **return** button on iOS keyboard superview expands.

It is Ok (Image below)

[image]

Strange behaviour - label with "Comment" has gone up and part of typed text also there (Image below)

[image]

When click on return button (Image below)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITextView` didn't know about his width constraint because it was added by code. So adding width constraint for `UITextView` solved the problem